# Extracting Variables from SSIS package stored in the msdb

Tags: sql, xml, variables, ssis

I need to audit over 100 SSIS packages inside the msdb and I need to pull all the variables and associated values from each package.  I have come up with the following script that is kind of there (only reading one package for now) so I can list everything within the DTS:Variable node but I'm not sure how just to extract each variable and value.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' as dts) 
SELECT Con.Str.value('.', 'varchar(400)')
FROM (
        SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), packagedata)) AS pkgXML
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90
    WHERE name = 'SSISPackageName'

        ) pkgblob
CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('//dts:Variable') as Con(Str)
```

Sample XML

```
<DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Expression" />
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EvaluateAsExpression">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Namespace">User</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ReadOnly">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="RaiseChangedEvent">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:VariableValue DTS:DataType="3">50000</DTS:VariableValue>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">DeleteBatchQty</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{2A967BFC-BE6C-41C8-B574-6CB94D09C96E}    </DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description" />
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName" />
  </DTS:Variable>
```

So I need ObjectName of "DeleteBatchQty" and it's value "50000" in the above example and ultimately a list of all the variables.

If anyone has the answer it would extremely appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

I first fill the XML into a dummy table to keep my test scenario close to your actual issue.

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(packagedata XML);
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
('<DTS:Variable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Expression" />
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EvaluateAsExpression">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Namespace">User</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ReadOnly">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="RaiseChangedEvent">0</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:VariableValue DTS:DataType="3">50000</DTS:VariableValue>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">DeleteBatchQty</DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{2A967BFC-BE6C-41C8-B574-6CB94D09C96E}    </DTS:Property>
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description" />
    <DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName" />
  </DTS:Variable>');

  ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' as DTS) 
   SELECT Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="Expression"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS Expression
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="EvaluateAsExpression"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS EvaluateAsExpression
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="Namespace"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS Namespace
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="ReadOnly"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS ReadOnly
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="RaiseChangedEvent"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS RaiseChangedEvent
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:VariableValue)[1]','varchar(max)') AS VariableValue
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="ObjectName"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS ObjectName
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="DTSID"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS DTSID
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="Description"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS Description
         ,Con.Str.value('(DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="CreationName"])[1]','varchar(max)') AS CreationName
   FROM (
        SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), packagedata)) AS pkgXML
        FROM @Dummy
        ) pkgblob
CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('/DTS:Variable') as Con(Str)
```

You may chose your fitting datatypes and not a `varchar(max)` in all places...

Comment: Thank you, the example work perfectly.  How can I load the whole package XML into the dummy table?

Comment: @PaulHR, try to replace your `;WITH   ...   FROM` with my `;WITH  ...  FROM`. If the `DTS:Variable` is not the up-most node, you should put a second slash in the `.nodes('//DTS:Variable')` or specify the full path. And be aware of XML being case sensitiv (Your namespace " AS dts" does not match with "DTS")

Comment: Perfect that worked.  Thank you.  It was the extra slash that I needed :)